# Wordpress: I want to get the name of a meta field

Tags: php, wordpress, post, metadata

[image: img]

I am using the Post Type Builder for Wordpress to create Custom Post Types.
I would like to get the name of a meta field in the front-end. I am able to get the values, but I would like the names. How could I do this?

For example, I have made a custom post type for a machine selling website.
The user is able to add a new machine (post type), add the building year, dimensions, weight and so (meta data).

I would like to display: **Year**: 2001. How can I get "Year"?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

Comment: That way I get the meta-key "ptb_jaar". I want the name of the meta-key "Jaar".

Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to use the Post Type Builder template editor (https://themify.me/docs/post-type-builder-plugin-documentation#templates).

If not that, then the simple answer is that you already know what the name of the field is since you're passing the key in. You can just hard-code that into your page template.

The final method would be to unserialze and parse out the ptb_plugin_options item from the wp_options table. This is one big blob that holds all of the config info for the plugin. You would retrieve it something like:

```
$ptb_plugin_options = unserialize(get_option('ptb_plugin_options'));
echo $ptb_plugin_options['cpt']['POSTTYPE']['meta_boxes']['text_1']['name'];
```

Replacing POSTTYPE with the actual posttype you're using and text_1 with the meta_key of the box in Post Type Builder.

Comment: Thank you very much!

I just want to make a very basic slider which loops through my custom posts and show some meta box labels. 

I'am going to look for another post type plugin which enable's me to use the labels easily.